# Self-Hosted Integration Runtime could not connect to Azure data factory while registering with keys

Tags: azure-data-factory

when i try to register with the authentication keys, im getting the below error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k16Qw.png)

Comment: Avoid posting images, paste error message as text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you hit some network issue. Maybe you can check if you have whitelist azure's IP range.

Answer (score 0):

A connection to the service back end is not possible for the self-hosted IR. Most often, the firewall, DNS, or enterprise network settings are to blame for this problem.

**To resolve this**

Check to see whether the integration runtime service is running. if it is running and no proxy is configured on the self-hosted IR run the below command in your Windows PowerShell, I will give you glimpse of error.

Code from Microsoft document

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("https://demofactorypratik.eastus.datafactory.azure.net/")
```

You can get the above link form **Integration runtimes** > **your self-hosted IR** > **Nodes** > **View Service URLs**.

**Expected result:**
[image]

If you get a "`Remote name could not be resolved`" message, there's a DNS issue. if you get an "`ssl/tls cert is not trusted`" message, then install the public certificate by using Certificate Manager. Go to **Event viewer (logs)** > **Applications and Services Logs** > **Integration Runtime**, here you can find check what's the exact issue.

[image]

**I can successfully be able to connect Self-hosted IR**

[image]

Also see, [Self-hosted IR connectivity issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/self-hosted-integration-runtime-troubleshoot-guide?tabs=data-factory#self-hosted-ir-connectivity-issues)